# pthread/pthreads error while building eigen

Tags: c++, pthreads, eigen

I am trying to build eigen library (C++). I have installed all the dependencies and I am running `cmake` to build the library. With respect to pthreads, the following is what the cmake has configured and found out in my system:

```
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
```

and later on, cmake halts with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_11c0c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_11c0c -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have found out that `pthread` and `pthreads` are the same library and are named differently for different architectures. If `pthread` is available in my system, why is cmake looking for `pthreads`. Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: You don't need to "build" Eigen.  It is header only.  The only time you need to use the build system is when you want to run the tests.

Comment: Yeah, actually I wanted to use cmake because I wanted it to install the headers to the right place (default include directory). I didn't realize that it was trying to build the tests. I copied the headers directory to `etc/include`. Eigen is working now. But the question remains - why was cmake looking for `pthreads` when `pthread` was available?

Comment: That is not from Eigen.  The `FindPastix.cmake` file uses [`find_package(Threads)`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindThreads.cmake) which is internal to CMake.  For some reason this looks for both, `pthread` and `pthreads`.